# Unable to install OpenLDAP on Red Hat Enterpise Linux

Tags: python, linux, openldap

I'm trying to install PythonLDAP on my remote server, and in order to do this I have to install OpenLDAP as a prerequisite.

I downloaded OpenLDAP, transferred it to my server, extracted it, ran the ./configure script, but when I type "make" in the home directory of OpenLDAP, it says:

> make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

And yet there is a configure script in this same directory, and there is also a Makefile.in file in this same directory. Why am I unable to run make? I have been building from source for years... and it usually runs smoothly. I don't understand why it won't run the make step.

This is the download site: http://www.openldap.org/software/download/

Comment: the configure script ran without errors ? (after configure you should have a Makefile without .in)

Comment: Building and installing from source is highly ill-advised. You end up with files on your system that RPM isnt aware of and this causes all sorts of dependency issues. There are numerous sources you can obtain OpenLDAP packages from, like the official RedHat repos.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to just install OpenLDAP from RedHat repositories? If you need development libraries to compile or do something with PythonLDAP you can install those too.

```
yum install openldap
yum install openldap-devel
```